# Change Tab color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used javascript tab to display contents based on tab selection. It's working perfectly. Only what i want to change is the background color of the tab. i need to display 4 different background colors on the four individual tabs. Inline css is not working because it's calling from javascript file. I got the code from here: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/

Code:

Html:

```
 <div class="tabber">
 <div class="tabbertab" style="background:#dadada">
 <h2 style="font-size:18px;">HR Policies</h2>
 <p>Content Display.</p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
  ul.tabbernav li a {
  background: #DDE;
  }
```

Above is the default background color for all tabs.

Javascript:

```
  if (!t.headingText) {
  /* Title was not found (or is blank) so automatically generate a
     number for the tab.
  */
  t.headingText = i + 1;
 }

 /* Create a list element for the tab */
 DOM_li = document.createElement("li");

 /* Save a reference to this list item so we can later change it to
   the "active" class */
 t.li = DOM_li;

 /* Create a link to activate the tab */
 DOM_a = document.createElement("a");
 DOM_a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t.headingText));
 DOM_a.href = "javascript:void(null);";
 DOM_a.title = t.headingText;
 DOM_a.onclick = this.navClick;

 /* Add some properties to the link so we can identify which tab
   was clicked. Later the navClick method will need this.
 */
 DOM_a.tabber = this;
 DOM_a.tabberIndex = i;

 /* Do we need to add an id to DOM_a? */
  if (this.addLinkId && this.linkIdFormat) {

  /* Determine the id name */
  aId = this.linkIdFormat;
  aId = aId.replace(/<tabberid>/gi, this.id);
  aId = aId.replace(/<tabnumberzero>/gi, i);
  aId = aId.replace(/<tabnumberone>/gi, i+1);
  aId = aId.replace(/<tabtitle>/gi, t.headingText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/gi, ''));

  DOM_a.id = aId;
 }

 /* Add the link to the list element */
 DOM_li.appendChild(DOM_a);

 /* Add the list element to the list */
 DOM_ul.appendChild(DOM_li);
 }
```

Comment: please update your full code

Comment: Hi Karthick, i got the code from here: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use a selector with higher specificity to override the default colors than `!important`,

try

```
.tabberlive ul.tabbernav li a {
 background: #DDE;
}
```

You can color each tab as follows: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/j8pbr/)

```
.tabberlive ul.tabbernav li:nth-child(1) a {
 background: cyan; /* color for 1st tab */
}
.tabberlive ul.tabbernav li:nth-child(2) a {
background: silver; /* color for 2nd tab */
}
.tabberlive ul.tabbernav li:nth-child(3) a {
background: yellow; /* color for 3rd tab */
}
.tabberlive ul.tabbernav li:nth-child(4) a {
background: cyan; /* color for 4th tab */
}
```

etc

Comment: Hi Tilwin, Thanks for the help. Now it's displaying individual color. But the active tab background color become overlapped: ul.tabbernav li.tabberactive a
{
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top-left-radius: 1em;
border-top-right-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

Comment: Hey thanks for active tab i have given !important. Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

**CSS:**

```
 ul.tabbernav li a {
  background: #DDE !important;
  }
```

`!important` this would `override` any of the properties that are being applied

**Hope this helps**

Comment: !important is terribly hack. Do not use this if possible. Instead of applying styles inline w/ JS, try switching in/out class names that will change the color. Maybe an overwriting "selected" class?